# How to watch changes to compiled CSS and update original SCSS?

Tags: node.js, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I know it sounds ridiculous, but **Chrome writes to the compiled CSS** when using the **Developer Tools -> Elements -> Styles** with workspace set up. It sees the original partial, but when changing a property, it writes to the compiled ([they say](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863408#c5) it's working as intended, lol). Therefore I would like to:

1. Watch or intercept 3rd party writes to compiled (changes that didn't occur from the compile due to regular --watch).
2. Map the change using the sourcemap to the original SCSS file.
3. Save the changed SCSS file.
4. That will trigger a new compile. The compiled CSS will probably be the same as how Chrome left it. But this time the values arrive from SCSS and will persist.

I know that if I change stuff on the Sources tab, it does save to the right file. But I don't get a live preview then playing directly with the SCSS file on the Sources tab, only if I save. **My workflow includes changing the design live** on the **Elements -> Style** tab, then (for now) copy pasting the values I like to the file. If I have to **switch to the Sources tab and I see the unchanged original values there** (paste the changes, save, refresh), I might as well just switch to VS Code to do the same thing, it defeats the purpose of how it should work (when no SCSS is thrown into the mix).

I'm using sass from npm but I see this reverse sync would be the task of a custom script that can somehow distinguish the process that wrote to the file to avoid an infinite loop. The files are local but in an Ubuntu VM that has a samba share so they are accessed via a drive letter in Windows (Chrome is told that path). The solution just has to work, I don't care what language or platform.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I kinda given up on it because when you start using more esoteric features of sass, it's going to get complicated. Like the style tab shows the resolved color values of variables. But it shouldn't just write that back into the original file. Did you mean to update the variable? Or just that single value? Would it accidentally discontinue use of the variable (like in a background shorthand when you touched something else next to that value). Sourcemap can tell you where it came from, but not more. The logic is still up to you that can't be automated I believe.